# Why is the time complexity of inserting an element into a set O(log N) and deletion O(N)?

Tags: c++, insert, set, time-complexity

Can someone please briefly explain, I googled it but only found time complexities without any explanation.

Comment: Whatever site you found using google that made that mistaken claim, add that site to your block list.

Comment: Please visit [ask] page to read who to ask a (good) question. This post body is missing the essential summary

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the time complexity of inserting an element into a set O(log N) and deletion O(N)?

The former is accurate, but the latter is not true; both removal and insertion of elements [is O(log N) time complexity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set):

> `std::set` is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type `Key`. Sorting is done using the key comparison function `Compare`. Search, **removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity**. Sets are usually implemented as red-black trees.

The `std::set` is typically implemented as [a red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), which fulfills the complexity requirement placed on the `std::set` associative container:

> [...] The insertion and deletion operations, along with the tree rearrangement and recoloring, are also performed in `O(log n)` time.